# Using Signalr on Angular 5 and Asp.net WebApi

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I am actually creating a chat with angular 5 and signalR on an ASP.NET Framework API. I followed the documentation but it's still not work. Here is my hub:

```
 public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public void Hello()
    {
        Clients.All.hello();
    }
}
```

Here is my startup class:

```
  app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            // Setup the CORS middleware to run before SignalR.
            // By default this will allow all origins. You can 
            // configure the set of origins and/or http verbs by
            // providing a cors options with a different policy.
            map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
            {
                EnableJSONP = true
            };

            // Run the SignalR pipeline. We're not using MapSignalR
            // since this branch already runs under the "/signalr"
            // path.
            
            map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        });
```

and here is my angular part which create the hubconnection:

```
ngOnInit() {
this._hubConnection = new HubConnection('http://localhost:58525/signalr/hubs');

this._hubConnection
  .start()
  .then(() => console.log('Connection started!'))
  .catch(err => console.log('Error while establishing connection :( : ' + err));

this._hubConnection.on('send', data => {
  console.log(data);
});
}
```

I get this error:
[image: this error]

Answer (score 0):

If your ASP.NET page runs on another server, then your URL looks not correct.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#crossdomain

You have to connect to:

```
this._hubConnection = new HubConnection('http://localhost:58525/signalr');
```